# How to track facebook shares

Tags: php, facebook

I have the following code to allow people to share a link on their facebook

```
<div class="fb_share">
    <a name="fb_share" type="button" share_url="http://www.handybook.com"
        href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share us on Facebook</a>
    <script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
```

How can I track whether someone actually shared the link after they shared the link? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may choose to incorporate [Gigya](http://www.gigya.com/share-plugin/) to facilitate and track sharing, not only on FB but across other social networks, too.

I've worked on projects where this served the purpose well.